# Opaqueness of nested element inside an opaque div

Tags: html, css

I have an opaque div.opaque containing another div.inner. Since inner div is contained inside opaque div, it becomes opaque as well. How can I override the opaqueness of inner div.

I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/wfWbX/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. A workaround is to put the inner `div` in the same level as the opaque `div`:

http://jsfiddle.net/wfWbX/10/

Comment: ok...thx. I was doing your suggestion already. Was just curious if its possible what I asked for. Thanks. Should I mark the answer as correct??

Comment: @gauravjain completely your call :), you could wait for a better answer if you wish, I don't mind at all :D

Comment: its 2013 and you still can't do this in css/html. damn it

Comment: 2014 is coming soon-ish in where I live.